# Time Series with Pandas / Cumulative average of previous values for different groups (lagged variabled for different groups)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to get the cummulative average of previous values for different gropus using Pandas.

My original dataframe(df) is:

```
idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Apr-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 5}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 3},{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 6}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 5}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 3},{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 9}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 6}, {'xx': 8}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx'])
df.index.names=['date','type']
df=df.reset_index()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y') 
df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
df['xx'] = df.xx.astype('float')
```

And the result I am looking for (cummulative average of previous values for the different types) looks like this:

```
         date type   xx        yy
0  2018-01-01    A  1.0       NaN
1  2018-01-01    B  5.0       NaN
2  2018-02-01    B  3.0  5.000000
3  2018-03-01    A  2.0  1.000000
4  2018-03-01    B  7.0  4.000000
5  2018-03-01    C  3.0       NaN
6  2018-04-01    A  1.0  1.500000
7  2018-04-01    B  6.0  5.000000
8  2018-05-01    B  3.0  5.250000
9  2018-06-01    A  5.0  1.333333
10 2018-06-01    B  2.0  4.800000
11 2018-06-01    C  3.0  3.000000
12 2018-07-01    A  1.0  2.250000
13 2018-08-01    B  9.0  4.333333
14 2018-08-01    C  3.0  3.000000
15 2018-09-01    A  2.0  2.000000
16 2018-09-01    B  7.0  5.000000
17 2018-10-01    C  3.0  3.000000
18 2018-10-01    A  6.0  2.000000
19 2018-10-01    B  8.0  5.250000
20 2018-11-01    A  2.0  2.571429
21 2018-12-01    B  7.0  5.555556
22 2018-12-01    C  9.0  3.000000
```

I tried the following Pandas code without success (it has an error when I do the rolling operation):

```
df['yy'] = (df.assign(H=(df.groupby('type').xx.transform('cumsum')/(df.groupby('type').xx.cumcount()+1)))).groupby('type').H.rolling(1).apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

Note that the first part of the code is working fine:

```
df['yy'] = (df.groupby('type').xx.transform('cumsum')/(df.groupby('type').xx.cumcount()+1))
```

** It would be useful if you can solve my error or if you propose another elegant way of doing the same with Pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using `expanding`

```
df.groupby('type')['xx'].expanding(min_periods=2).mean().\
     reset_index(level=0,drop=True).reindex(df.index)
date        type
2018-01-01  A            NaN
            B            NaN
2018-02-01  B       4.000000
2018-03-01  A       1.500000
            B       5.000000
            C            NaN
2018-04-01  A       1.333333
            B       5.250000
2018-05-01  B       4.800000
2018-06-01  A       2.250000
            B       4.333333
            C       3.000000
2018-07-01  A       2.000000
2018-08-01  B       5.000000
            C       3.000000
2018-09-01  A       2.000000
            B       5.250000
2018-10-01  C       3.000000
            A       2.571429
            B       5.555556
2018-11-01  A       2.500000
2018-12-01  B       5.700000
            C       4.200000
Name: xx, dtype: float64
```

Comment: ## NOT WHAT I ASKED ## I MENTIONED PREVIOUS/ PAST PERIODS (NOT INClUDiNG CURRENT PERIOD ##

Answer (score 0):

### I found two solution, using shift():

```
df['yy'] = (df.assign(H=(df.groupby('type').xx.transform('cumsum')/(df.groupby('type').xx.cumcount()+1)))).groupby('type').H.shift()
```

And (using rolling):

```
df['yy'] = (df.assign(H=(df.groupby('type').xx.transform('cumsum')/(df.groupby('type').xx.cumcount()+1)))).groupby('type').H.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[-2]).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).reindex(df.index)
```

Any other way is welcome!